# How to convert POST curl request to Retrofit Request in Android?

Tags: java, android, curl, facebook-graph-api, retrofit2

I'm trying to represent the below curl request in android using Retrofit,

```
curl -i -X POST \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/1234567890/messages \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer  ucuzZCQv9qb--token--0UMHaEhLwvuOW6WvapUGuPAkrDchj' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{ "messaging_product": "whatsapp", "to": "9477number", "type": "template", "template": { "name": "hello_world", "language": { "code": "en_US" } } }'
```

> My API Service class

```
public interface APIService {
    @POST("{phoneNoId}/messages")
    Call<MsgResponse> SendMsg(@Path("phoneNoId") String phoneNoId,
                              @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                              @Header("Content-Type") String types,
                              @Body String msgObj
    );
}
```

> My API calling place in the MainActivity.class

```
APIService apiService=RetroInstance.getRetrofitClient().create(APIService.class);

            Call<MsgResponse> call=apiService.SendMsg("100798385993185",
                    "Bearer 5iWIZBiI5vogoNZBKbBJ0oZAibvZBG---token--xIcDPoW",
                                                     "application/json",
                                                     jsonBody
                                                    );

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+call.toString());

            call.enqueue(new Callback<MsgResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<MsgResponse> call, Response<MsgResponse> response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<MsgResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getStackTrace().toString());
                }
            });
```

here `jsonbody` I'm getting the json object using gson like below `String jsonBody=gson.toJson(msgObj);`

**My Request is successful but I'm getting 400 error code** error message below, **what went wrong here, Thank you**

```
onResponse: Response{protocol=h2, code=400, message=, url=https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/1234567890/messages}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can pass headers to your `Retrofit` request using `Interceptor`. This might not be a perfect way, but it works quite good, These headers are sent with every API request.

First, extend `Interceptor` and add the header to the request as shown below:

```
class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  @Override public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    Request newRequest = request.newBuilder()
       .header("Authorization","YOUR AUTH CODE HERE")
       .header("Content-Type","application/json").build(); 
    return chain.proceed(newRequest);
  }
}
```

Now you can use this custom Interceptor with OkHttpClient :

```
OkHttpClientBuilder builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor());
```

Use this client while building the Retrofit object:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(YOUR_BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClientBuilder.build())
            .build()
```

Comment: It's not working ❌

Comment: is there any error you are getting or something else? We use same code mentioned above in our projects.

Comment: I figured out the issue, the issue was I'm passing the body as a JSON String but, I just want to pass as a model object